# TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me out? I'm a beginner in python and this error is bugging me. The function is basically for connected component labelling but I'm finding it difficult to get the maximum value using python's max() function as shown below.

There must be some trivial mistake I am missing out. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import disk

%matplotlib inline

def ccl(img):

    ##### first pass #####
    curr_label = 1;
    img = np.array(img)
    labels = np.array(img)

    # storing label conversions
    label_conv = []
    label_conv.append([])
    label_conv.append([])

    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(img)):
        for j in range(1, len(img[0])):

            if img[i][j] > 0:
                label_x = int(labels[i][j - 1])
                label_y = int(labels[i - 1][j])

                if label_x > 0:
                    # both x and y have a label
                    if label_y > 0:

                        if not label_x == label_y:
                            labels[i][j] = min(label_x, label_y)
                            #print("i: ", i, "j: ", j)
                            #print("label_x: ", type(label_x), "label_y: ", type(label_y))
                            max_label = max(label_x, label_y)

                            if max_label not in label_conv[0]:
                                label_conv[0].append(max(label_x, label_y))
                                label_conv[1].append(min(label_x, label_y))

                            elif max(label_x, label_y) in label_conv[0]:
                                ind = label_conv[0].index(max(label_x, label_y))

                                if label_conv[1][ind] > min(label_x, label_y):
                                    l = label_conv[1][ind]
                                    label_conv[1][ind] = min(label_x, label_y)
                                    while l in label_conv[0] and count < 100:
                                        count += 1
                                        ind = label_conv[0].index(l)
                                        l = label_conv[1][ind]
                                        label_conv[1][ind] = min(label_x, label_y)

                                    label_conv[0].append(l)
                                    label_conv[1].append(min(label_x, label_y))

                        else:
                            labels[i][j] = label_y
                    # only x has a label
                    else:
                        labels[i][j] = label_x

                # only y has a label
                elif label_y > 0:
                    labels[i][j] = label_y

                # neither x nor y has a label
                else:
                    labels[i][j] = curr_label
                    curr_label += 1

    ##### second pass #####
    count = 1
    for idx, val in enumerate(label_conv[0]):

        if label_conv[1][idx] in label_conv[0] and count < 100:
            count += 1
            ind = label_conv[0].index(label_conv[1][idx])
            label_conv[1][idx] = label_conv[1][ind]

    for i in range(1, len(labels)):
        for j in range(1, len(labels[0])):

            if labels[i][j] in label_conv[0]:
                ind = label_conv[0].index(labels[i][j])
                labels[i][j] = label_conv[1][ind]

    return labels


img = cv2.imread("..\\disks.png", 0)

img2 = cv2.bitwise_not(img, mask = None)

SE = disk(25)
img_eroded = cv2.erode(img2,SE) #Erode the image

plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.imshow(img_eroded, cmap="gray")
plt.title('Image')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

labels = ccl(img_eroded)

print("size: ",  labels)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.imshow(img_eroded, cmap="gray")
plt.title('Image')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Here is the error output that I'm getting.

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-04f5b3d4d1e5> in <module>
    103 plt.yticks([])
    104 
--> 105 labels = ccl(img_eroded)
    106 
    107 print("size: ",  labels)

<ipython-input-83-04f5b3d4d1e5> in ccl(img)
     34                             #print("i: ", i, "j: ", j)
     35                             #print("label_x: ", type(label_x), "label_y: ", type(label_y))
---> 36                             max_label = max(label_x, label_y)
     37 
     38                             if max_label not in label_conv[0]:

TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object is not callable
enter code here
```

Comment: You assigned a variable named `max` sometime earlier. Restart the kernel and try again, and make sure you do not override Python's built-ins `max`, `list` etc.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you have previously assigned `max` as a variable pointing to a numpy int. Then when you try to call the `max()` function it tries to call the variable you have created instead.

Clear your namespace, and run it again.