# Find the min max value of a column of a DataFrame whose entries are arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to find the min max value of a column which consists of array entries. Yet I find my code reasonable

```
  error min_=100
  max_=-100
  for id in range(len(df)):
      if np.min(df['color'].iloc[id]) < min_:
         np.min_=min(df['color'].iloc[id])
      if np.max(df['color'].iloc[id]) > max_:
         np.max=np.max(df['color'].iloc[id])
```

I get the error

```
'numpy.float32' object is not callable
```

How I could fix it?

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988736/typeerror-numpy-float32-object-is-not-callable ?

Comment: This line causes the issue `np.max=np.max(df['color'].iloc[id])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
      if np.max(df['color'].iloc[id]) > max_:
         np.max=np.max(df['color'].iloc[id])
```

Problem is that you assign `np.max` as the result of `np.max(df['color'].iloc[id])` which returns `numpy.float32` in the first loop.

In the following loop, `np.max(..)` is called in `if` statement, However, `np.max` has been set to `numpy.float32` previously. It means you are calling something like `3.4(df['color'].iloc[id])`, so the error occurs.

You can use [`Series.min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) or [`Series.min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) to get the minimum/maximum of the values

```py
minimum = df['color'].min()
```